# How can I build a string from a list of strings in my viewmodel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have these properties in my viewmodel:

```
public string FullInfo => LastName + ", " + FirstName
    + " (" + string.Join(",",EmployeeRoles) + ")";
public List<EmployeeRoleViewModel> EmployeeRoles { get; set; }
```

... which produces this output:

> Doe, John ({Project name}.Models.EmployeeRoleViewModel, {Project name}.Models.EmployeeRoleViewModel)

The output I'm looking for is this:

> Doe, John (Assisting Manager, Senior developer)

The last bit with the `string.Join` is not doing what I want. I want to add a comma separated list of `Title`s from `EmployeeRoles`, which looks like this:

```
public class EmployeeRoleViewModel
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

How can this be acheived?

Comment: May be `string.Join(",", EmployeeRoles.Where(r => r.Selected ).Select(r => r.Title ).ToArray())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should target the `Title` property from `EmployeeRoles` object

```
public string FullInfo => LastName + ", " + FirstName
+ " (" + string.Join(",",EmployeeRoles.Where(r => r.Selected).Select(r => r.Title ).ToArray()) + ")";
```

Comment: Tested on .Net 4.5 and it does not produce correct result, submitted fix edit

Comment: @hessamhedieh, I am sure you must have imported `System.Linq` namespace

Answer (score 1):

`EmployeeRoles` is a class which it's `.ToString()` is not what you want. you have to selected it's titles:

```
public string FullInfo => LastName + ", " + FirstName
    + " (" + string.Join(",",EmployeeRoles.Select(er => er.Title)) + ")";
```

Comment: Thank you. Satpal was 1 minute quicker, so I accepted his answer. But it seems that the addition of `.ToArray()`, which Satpal has in his answer, is not necessary. It works both with and without. So I'm using your solution. :)